# WPF Tetris Index Out Of Range Exception

Tags: wpf, outofrangeexception, tetris

I am very new and very inexperienced. I have downloaded a WPF version of tetris from MSDN to review the code and try to see whats going on but there is an error in the program and I'm not sure what is causing it. The exception details are as follows:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=WPFTetris
  StackTrace:
       at WPFTetris.Window1.PaintBlock() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 544
       at WPFTetris.Window1.RotateBlockClockwise() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 232
       at WPFTetris.Window1.HandleKeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 202
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at WPFTetris.App.Main() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

A portion of the source code is below...

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=WPFTetris
  StackTrace:
       at WPFTetris.Window1.PaintBlock() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 544
       at WPFTetris.Window1.RotateBlockClockwise() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 232
       at WPFTetris.Window1.HandleKeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\Window1.xaml.cs:line 202
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at WPFTetris.App.Main() in C:\Code Snips and LIT\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\WPFTetris\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

A portion of the source code is below...

```
namespace WPFTetris

public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
{


    public Label[,] blocksControls;

    public Point[] fallingBlock;
    public Point fallingBlockPosition;

    public Brush fallingBlockBrush;

    public Brush NO_BLOCK_BRUSH;
    public Brush FLASH_ROW_BRUSH;

    public Thickness NO_BLOCK_THICKNESS;
    public Thickness IN_BLOCK_THICKNESS;


    public int nextLevelScoreThreshold;
    public int currentScore;
    public int currentLevel;
    public const int ROW_REMOVED_POINTS = 100;

    public bool blockJustShowed;


    /* Everytime the Timer overflows the system does one move, 
     * either move the block down, or show next block */
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer blockStepTimer;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void SetGridBackroundImage()
    {
        //ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush(
    }

    void Window1_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /**/
        SetGridBackroundImage();

        /**/
        nextLevelScoreThreshold = 500;
        currentLevel = 0;
        currentScore = 0;

        NO_BLOCK_BRUSH = Brushes.Transparent;
        FLASH_ROW_BRUSH = Brushes.White;
        NO_BLOCK_THICKNESS = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        IN_BLOCK_THICKNESS = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);

        /*Init blocks array*/
        int rowCount;
        int columnCount;

        rowCount = tetrisGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        /*init fallingBlock array*/
        fallingBlock = new Point[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < fallingBlock.Length; i++)
        {
            fallingBlock[i] = new Point(0,0);
        }

        /**/
        fallingBlockPosition = new Point(0,0);

        /**/
        blockStepTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        blockStepTimer.Interval = 700;
        blockStepTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(blockStepTimer_Tick);
        blockStepTimer.Enabled = false;

        AddBlocksControls();
    }


    private void AddBlocksControls()
    {
        int rowCount;
        int columnCount;

        rowCount = tetrisGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        blocksControls = new Label[rowCount,columnCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
            {
                Label blockLabel = new Label();
                blockLabel.Background = NO_BLOCK_BRUSH;
                blocksControls[i, j] = blockLabel;



                Border blockBorder = new Border();
                blockBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                blockBorder.Child = blockLabel;

                /* Can't believe te following block of code works. 
                 * where the hell are the column and the row stored?!?
                 * Not in tetrisGrid, because the VM only knows that it
                 * is part of tetrisGrid _after_ both the row and col have
                 * been set.
                 */
                Grid.SetRow(blockBorder, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(blockBorder, j);
                tetrisGrid.Children.Add(blockBorder);


            }
        }


    }

    public void StartNewGame(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        blockStepTimer.Start();
        ShowNextBlock();
    }


    public void btnDebugAction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Type = " + tetrisGrid.GetType().ToString()
            + "\n\n IsEquals to Grid.Type() = ");
    }





    private void blockStepTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveBlockDown();
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Handles all KeyDown events for all controls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void HandleKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
                MoveBlockLeft();
                break;

            case Key.Right:
                MoveBlockRight();
                break;

            case Key.Down:
                MoveBlockDown();
                break;

            case Key.Up:
                RotateBlockClockwise();
                break;

            case Key.Pause:
                TogglePauseState();
                break;

            case Key.F2:
                StartNewGame(null, null);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    private void RotateBlockClockwise()
    {
        ClearBlock();

        //using regular for loop beacuse foreach causes iterator problems
        for (int i = 0; i < fallingBlock.Length; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)fallingBlock[i].X;
            fallingBlock[i].X = fallingBlock[i].Y;
            fallingBlock[i].Y = -1 * x;
        }

        PaintBlock();
    }

    private void MoveBlockRight()
    {
        LinkedList<Point> rightestPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();
        int rightestX = int.MinValue;  //the highestValue, which is the lowest row

        foreach (Point p in fallingBlock)
        {
            if (rightestX == p.X)
            {
                rightestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
            else if (rightestX < p.X)
            {
                rightestX = (int)p.X;
                rightestPoints.Clear();
                rightestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
        }

        int baseX = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.X);
        int baseY = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.Y);

        int gridColumnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        /*Check that it can move down*/
        bool canMoveRight = true;
        foreach (Point p in rightestPoints)
        {
            /* -1 to check if the next possible value goes out of bounds*/
            if ((baseX + p.X + 1) >= gridColumnCount)
            {
                canMoveRight = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (blocksControls[(int)(baseY + p.Y), (int)(p.X + baseX + 1)].Background != NO_BLOCK_BRUSH)
            {
                canMoveRight = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!canMoveRight)
        {
            return;
        }

        /*move right*/
        ClearBlock();
        fallingBlockPosition.X++;
        PaintBlock();

    }


    private void MoveBlockLeft()
    {
        LinkedList<Point> leftestPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();
        int leftestX = int.MaxValue;  //the highestValue, which is the lowest row

        foreach (Point p in fallingBlock)
        {
            if (leftestX == p.X)
            {
                leftestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
            else if (leftestX > p.X)
            {
                leftestX = (int)p.X;
                leftestPoints.Clear();
                leftestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
        }

        int baseX = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.X);
        int baseY = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.Y);



        /*Check that it can move down*/
        bool canMoveLeft = true;
        foreach (Point p in leftestPoints)
        {
            /* -1 to check if the next possible value goes out of bounds*/
            if ((baseX + p.X - 1) < 0)
            {
                canMoveLeft = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (blocksControls[(int)(baseY + p.Y), (int)(p.X + baseX - 1)].Background != NO_BLOCK_BRUSH)
            {
                canMoveLeft = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!canMoveLeft)
        {
            return;
        }

        /*move left*/
        ClearBlock();
        fallingBlockPosition.X--;
        PaintBlock();

    }

    private void MoveBlockDown()
    {
        LinkedList<Point> lowestPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();
        int lowestY = int.MinValue;  //the highestValue, which is the lowest row

        foreach (Point p in fallingBlock)
        {
            if(lowestY == p.Y)
            {
                lowestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
            else if (lowestY < p.Y)
            {
                lowestY = (int)p.Y;
                lowestPoints.Clear();
                lowestPoints.AddFirst(p);
            }
        }

        int baseX = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.X);
        int baseY = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.Y);


        int gridRowCount = tetrisGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;

        /*Check that it can move down*/
        bool canMoveDown = true;
        foreach (Point p in lowestPoints)
        {
            /* +1 to check if the next possible value goes out of bounds*/
            if ((baseY + p.Y + 1) >= gridRowCount)
            {
                canMoveDown = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (blocksControls[(int)(baseY + p.Y + 1), (int)(p.X + baseX)].Background != NO_BLOCK_BRUSH)
            {
                if (blockJustShowed)
                {
                    LooseGame();
                    return;
                }

                canMoveDown = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!canMoveDown)
        {
            CheckForRowCompleted();
            ShowNextBlock();
            return; 
        }


        /*move down*/
        ClearBlock();
        fallingBlockPosition.Y++;
        blockJustShowed = false;
        PaintBlock();

    }

    private void CheckForRowCompleted()
    {
        int rowCount = tetrisGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        int columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        int completedRow = -1;
        for (int row = rowCount - 1; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            bool completed = true;
            for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
            {
                if (blocksControls[row, col].Background == NO_BLOCK_BRUSH)
                {
                    completed = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (completed)
            {
                completedRow = row;
                break;
            }
        }


        if (completedRow != -1)
        {
            //FlashTetrisRow(completedRow);
            RemoveTetrisRow(completedRow);
            IncrementScore(ROW_REMOVED_POINTS);
            CheckForRowCompleted(); // and remove another one if exists
        }
    }



    /*Not being used right now*/
    private void FlashTetrisRow(int rowToFlash)
    {

        blockStepTimer.Stop();
        PaintRow(rowToFlash, FLASH_ROW_BRUSH);
        //Thread.Sleep(900);
    }

    private void RemoveTetrisRow(int rowToRemove)
    {
        int columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        for (int row = rowToRemove; row > 0; row--)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
            {
                blocksControls[row, col].Background = blocksControls[row - 1, col].Background;

                Border currentRowBorder = ((Border)blocksControls[row, col].Parent);
                Border upperRowBorder =  ((Border)blocksControls[row - 1, col].Parent);
                currentRowBorder.BorderThickness = upperRowBorder.BorderThickness;
            }
        }


        //clear topmost row
        for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
        {
            PaintRow(0, NO_BLOCK_BRUSH);

            Border blockBorder = (Border)blocksControls[0, col].Parent;
            blockBorder.BorderThickness = NO_BLOCK_THICKNESS;

        }
    }

    public void IncrementScore(int amount)
    {
        currentScore += amount;
        scoreLabel.Content = "" + currentScore;

        if (currentScore >= nextLevelScoreThreshold)
        {
            currentLevel++;
            levelLabel.Content = "" + currentLevel;

            nextLevelScoreThreshold += 10 * ROW_REMOVED_POINTS;

            blockStepTimer.Interval = (int)(.85 * blockStepTimer.Interval);
        }

        scoreLabel.Content = "" + currentScore;            
    }


    /* Paints only one row. Good for doing the flashing when a row is ocmpleted,
     * amongst other things. */
    private void PaintRow(int row, Brush brush)
    {
        int columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        for( int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
        {
            blocksControls[row, col].Background = brush;
        }
    }


    private void ShowNextBlock()
    {
        int columnCount = tetrisGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        fallingBlock = GenerateRandomBlock();
        fallingBlockPosition = new Point(columnCount / 2,1);
        PaintBlock();
        blockJustShowed = true;
    }

    private void ClearBlock()
    {
        foreach (Point p in fallingBlock)
        {
            int i = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.X + p.X);
            int j = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.Y + p.Y);

            blocksControls[j,i].Background = NO_BLOCK_BRUSH;

            Border blockBorder = (Border)blocksControls[j, i].Parent;
            blockBorder.BorderThickness = NO_BLOCK_THICKNESS;

        }
    }

    private void PaintBlock()
    {
        foreach (Point p in fallingBlock)
        {
            int i = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.X + p.X);
            int j = (int)(fallingBlockPosition.Y + p.Y);

            blocksControls[j, i].Background = fallingBlockBrush;

            Border blockBorder = (Border)blocksControls[j, i].Parent;
            blockBorder.BorderThickness = IN_BLOCK_THICKNESS;
        }

    }


    private void LooseGame()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Lost");
        blockStepTimer.Stop();
    }



    private void TogglePauseState()
    {
        /*Toggle boolean value*/
        blockStepTimer.Enabled = !blockStepTimer.Enabled;
    }

    private Point[] GenerateRandomBlock()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        switch (rand.Next() % 7)
        {
            case 0: //T
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Green;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(-1,0),
                    new Point(0,-1),
                    new Point(1,0),
                };

            case 1: //LDer
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Red;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(0,-1),
                    new Point(0,1),
                    new Point(1,1),
                };

            case 2: // _
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Lime;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(-1,0),
                    new Point(1,0),
                    new Point(2,0),
                };

            case 3: //LIzq
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Orange;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(0,-1),
                    new Point(0,1),
                    new Point(-1,1),
                };


            case 4: //SDer (Z)
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Purple;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(-1,0),
                    new Point(0,1),
                    new Point(1,1),
                };


            case 5: //SIzq (S)
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(1,0),
                    new Point(0,1),
                    new Point(-1,1),
                };

            case 6: //Cuadro
                fallingBlockBrush = Brushes.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                return new Point[]{
                    new Point(0,0),
                    new Point(0,1),
                    new Point(1,0),
                    new Point(1,1),
                };

            default:
                return null;

        }
    }
}
```

There is a lot more code but this is the section that I believe the error is in. If any other information is needed please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blocksControls[j, i].Background = fallingBlockBrush;
```

i, j is referencing a non-exisitent index within `blocksControls`. As to why that is the case you would need to debug the code under execution to get an understanding on why that index is non-existent.

Comment: If this helps, the error occurs if the falling block is oriented resulting in the block moving outside of the game grid. I'm thinking that if I insert an if statement to test whether the block falls outside of the game grid and if true push the blocks into the grid the game will stop bombing out.